# pack_forget something wrong with destroying image - tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.3

In my program, I have encountered an error, and I don't know what is causing it.

Piece of Code:

```
sunPic = r'sun.gif'
mercPic = r'merc.gif'


buttonFrame = Frame(root)
buttonFrame.pack(side=LEFT)

textFrame = Frame(root)
textFrame.pack(side=TOP)


def sunInfo():
    textFrame.destroy()
    sunImage = PhotoImage(file=sunPic)
    img1 = Label(textFrame, image = sunImage)
    img1.pack()
    img1.image = sunImage

def mercInfo():
    textFrame.destroy()
    mercImage = PhotoImage(file=mercPic)
    img2 = Label(textFrame, image = mercImage).pack()
    img2.image = mercImage



sun = Button(buttonFrame, text="THE SUN",command=sunInfo)
sun.pack(side=TOP)

mercury = Button(buttonFrame, text="MERCURY",command=mercInfo)
mercury.pack(side=TOP)
```

And with that code, I get this error when I click on either THE SUN or MERCURY button:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1475, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\python\Projects for Parliament\universe\infoUniverse.py", line 30, in sunInfo
    img1 = Label(textFrame, image = sunImage)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2596, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2075, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".45448776"
```

What is wrong/what has caused this error?

**EDIT:**

I have changed it so the functions are like this:

```
def sunInfo():
    textFrame.pack_forget()
    sunImage = PhotoImage(file=sunPic)
    img1 = Label(textFrame, image = sunImage)
    img1.image = sunImage
    img1.pack()


def mercInfo():
    textFrame.pack_forget()
    mercImage = PhotoImage(file=mercPic)
    img2 = Label(textFrame, image = mercImage)
    img2.image = mercImage
    img2.pack()
```

But, whenever I run the program and press the buttons, the image does not come up.

Answer (score 0):

Two lines before the line that is causing the error, you destroy `textFrame`. Then, you try to use `textFrame` as the parent for `img1`. You can't use a widget once it has been destroyed.

Comment: Thank you, I changed it so I used pack_forget(). But now, the images aren't showing up?

Comment: When you use `pack_forget()` you're telling the frame to _not_ be displayed, so any image inside the frame will also _not_ be displayed.